# "parcella_pk" not okay there, it cause a "ValueError". What should I use?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-3.0

I don't know what type of data should I use there. With primary key I think is there are no problem. But it's not that what I needed.

This is part of my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Parcella(models.Model):
    ###
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.parcellanev

class Muvelet(models.Model):
    ###
    parcella = models.ForeignKey(Parcella, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is part of my views.py:

```
@login_required
def muvelethozzaadas(request, parcella_pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'foldmuv/muvelethozzaadas.html', {'form':MuveletForm()})
    else:
        try:
            form = MuveletForm(request.POST)
            ujmuvelet = form.save(commit=False)
            ujmuvelet.parcella = parcella_pk
            ujmuvelet.save()
            return redirect('parcellak')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'foldmuv/muvelethozzaadas.html', {'form':MuveletForm(), 'error':'Nem megfelelő adat. Kérlek prbáld újra!'})
```

This is part of my parcellaegy.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'muvelethozzaadas' parcella.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Hozzáadás</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You have to get object of  `Parcella` using `parcella_pk` and assign that object to `ujmuvelet.parcella` as...

```
parcella_obj = Parcella.objects.get(id=parcella_pk)
ujmuvelet.parcella = parcella_obj 
ujmuvelet.save()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208678/discussion-on-answer-by-mk-patel-parcella-pk-not-okay-there-it-cause-a-value).